# Problems with Admingenerator Bundle

Tags: symfony

I try to tape this command:

```
php symfony doctrine:generate-admin backend User
```

but i have this **error**:

```
Could not open input file: symfony
```

What i have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate with your shell to the right place where symfony file is located?

And in symfony 2 its rather console then symfony

(This is just a suggestion ofc, I dont know where your website is stored. You need to know the path by yourself, but it could look like this:

```
cd "/var/www/mywebsite/app"
```

And then

```
php console doctrine:generate-admin backend User
```

Comment: Yeah i do it and i had this: Could not open input file: console. Maybe the AdminGenrator bundle is not installed correctly ?!